# С одной стороны соблюдать контейнер, а с другой прижать к краю екрана

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

возникла такая задача. Нужно сверстать слайдер, с права он должен быть прижат к краю устройства, а с лева должен соблюдать контейнер. И это должно работать при разных разрешениях. Может кто делал подобные роботы, и знает как это можно реализовать? Фото как должно быть прикремлю. Заранее спасибо [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Добавь overflow:hidden для родителя

Comment: Точнее: ваши items находятся внутри одного блока, тот должен быть внутри другого блока у которого есть overflow:hidden

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]